# Image is not attached to intent

Tags: android, android-intent

```
String url = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), v.getDrawingCache(), "title", null);
final Intent intent = new Intent(     android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, url);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

When I choose any app from chooser it doesn't see an image

Comment: I think gallery not open ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya what? Why should it be opened?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code...

```
 public void addAttachments(View v)
{

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("application/image");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/TestImage.jpeg"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per new api level you can't get uri data so you can ignore restricted policy

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

String url = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), v.getDrawingCache(), "title", null);
```